# Extract items from an array containing arrays with n-depth in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to extract all the elements from an array such as this: [[42, 43, 46], [23,64], [2, [2,3]]]. I figured a recursive method approach would work, but recursion is a relatively new concept to me in Ruby. Is recursion the best solution or is there a better method? I was able to extract the first deepest item within the array with this method:

```
def list_items(array)
  return array if array.is_a? Integer
  array = array.shift
  list_items(array)
end

set = [[42,43,46],[23,64],[2,[2,3]]]
result = list_items(set)
p result
```

Comment: Is your expected output `[2,3]` ?

Comment: I want to create a 1 dimensional array of all the items. result = [42,43,46,23,64,2,2,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) method.

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of self (**recursively**).

```
set = [[42,43,46],[23,64],[2,[2,3]]]
set.flatten # => [42, 43, 46, 23, 64, 2, 2, 3]
```